# Creating Sapling Tree in the Python Console

Tags: python, scripting, sapling-addon

I'm trying to create a Sapling Tree object using Python. The Sapling Tree is an object that comes from this add-on: 
https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Curve/Sapling_Tree

I'm able to create it using the UI (Add > Curve > Sapling Tree Gen). I can see the command executed by the UI in the Info window. That command is:

```
bpy.ops.curve.tree_add(do_update=True, bevel=False, prune=False, showLeaves=False, useArm=False, seed=0, handleType='0', levels=2, length=(1, 0.3, 0.6, 0.45), lengthV=(0, 0, 0, 0), taperCrown=0, branches=(0, 50, 30, 10), curveRes=(8, 5, 3, 1), curve=(0, -40, -40, 0), curveV=(20, 50, 75, 0), curveBack=(0, 0, 0, 0), baseSplits=0, segSplits=(0, 0, 0, 0), splitByLen=True, rMode='rotate', splitAngle=(0, 0, 0, 0), splitAngleV=(0, 0, 0, 0), scale=13, scaleV=3, attractUp=(0, 0, 0.5, 0.5), attractOut=(0, 0, 0, 0), shape='7', shapeS='4', customShape=(0.5, 1, 0.3, 0.5), branchDist=1, nrings=0, baseSize=0.4, baseSize_s=0.25, splitHeight=0.2, splitBias=0, ratio=0.015, minRadius=0.0015, closeTip=False, rootFlare=1, autoTaper=True, taper=(1, 1, 1, 1), radiusTweak=(1, 1, 1, 1), ratioPower=1.1, downAngle=(90, 110, 45, 45), downAngleV=(0, 80, 10, 10), useOldDownAngle=False, useParentAngle=True, rotate=(99.5, 137.5, 137.5, 137.5), rotateV=(15, 0, 0, 0), scale0=1, scaleV0=0.1, pruneWidth=0.4, pruneBase=0.3, pruneWidthPeak=0.6, prunePowerHigh=0.5, prunePowerLow=0.001, pruneRatio=1, leaves=25, leafDownAngle=45, leafDownAngleV=10, leafRotate=137.5, leafRotateV=0, leafScale=0.17, leafScaleX=1, leafScaleT=0, leafScaleV=0, leafShape='hex', leafangle=0, horzLeaves=True, leafDist='6', bevelRes=0, resU=4, armAnim=False, previewArm=False, leafAnim=False, frameRate=1, loopFrames=0, wind=1, gust=1, gustF=0.075, af1=1, af2=1, af3=4, makeMesh=False, armLevels=2, boneStep=(1, 1, 1, 1))
```

But, when I copy and paste that command into the Python Console and run it, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<blender_console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.78\scripts\modules\bpy\ops.py", line 189, in __call__
    ret = op_call(self.idname_py(), None, kw)
RuntimeError: Error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.78\scripts\addons\add_curve_sapling\__init__.py", line 911, in execute
    addTree(self)
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.78\scripts\addons\add_curve_sapling\utils.py", line 1424, in addTree
    bend = props.bend#
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.78\scripts\modules\bpy_types.py", line 605, in __getattribute__
    return super().__getattribute__(attr)
AttributeError: 'AddTree' object has no attribute 'bend'

location: C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.78\scripts\modules\bpy\ops.py:189
```

I am able to copy and paste the UI command for creating a native object (i.e. a bezier curve), and that works just fine. I'm not sure whether this error has to do the Sapling Tree specifically, or applies to all add-on objects.

I understand that using `bpy.ops`commands are notoriously finicky, but I cannot find any other method to create the Sapling Tree since it isn't a native object.

I am running Blender 2.78 64-bit on Windows 10.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Using [`'INVOKE_DEFAULT'` Execution Context](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.ops.html?highlight=invoke_default#execution-context)   to your operator call always creates default**

```
bpy.ops.curve.tree_add('INVOKE_DEFAULT')
```

"Basically" this emulates the pressing (invoking) of button / menu in UI, and calls the invoke method, that in this case is required. This will create the default tree "quaking aspen"

**Note** using 'INVOKE' is calling the preset

`bpy.ops.sapling.importdata(filename="callistemon.py")` is hardcoded into the `invoke` method, changing other settings with `'INVOKE_DEFAULT'` will have no effect.  Will always get this sucker when invoked.

[image]

**Fixing to call from command line.**

**Edit**: it appears the `bend` parameter has been not completely edited out of the addon.  . For now to fix, run the addon and right click on any operator property and "view source". This will open `__init__.py` from the addon in  your text editor. (Or go to `addons/add_curve_sapling` in filebrowser and open with text editor of choice)

Search for bend around line 713 and remove the quotes `"""` from above and below the property definition.

[image]

**EDIT**

As of 2.83 still need to make edit above as well as commenting out line 1611 in utils.py

```
#cu.use_uv_as_generated = True
```

Save the text file, hit <kbd>F8</kbd> to reload addons.
Or for 2.8 run

```
bpy.ops.script.reload()
```

Now it will execute correctly with

```
bpy.ops.curve.tree_add(some_parameter=some_setting)
```

**Test in 2.83** using command from question crunched into console I get

[image]

producing

[image]

Comment: This has the effect of ignoring parameters and uses only the defaults - any other ideas if I want to provide actual parameters?

Comment: @Oliver correct, looked into it and added needed edit above.  Prob needs reporting to tracker.

Comment: @Oliver also check out https://github.com/abpy/improved-sapling-tree-generator

Answer (score 1):

Ok here is what worked for me: Go to your add-on folder - add_curve_sapling and right click on the *init*.py file. Choose edit in notepad. Use Shortcut cmd+f and type in "bend". Get rid of every comment #Hashtag where it says something with "bend "unless the one which says box.label(" ").

Comment: Deleting comments does absolutely nothing to the functionality of the code. This is not a viable answer.

Comment: I just searched for "bend" in [here](https://svn.blender.org/svnroot/bf-extensions/trunk/py/scripts/addons/add_curve_sapling/__init__.py) and none of the lines it turns up are commented.

Comment: Needed the `INVOKE_DEFAULT` execution context, see answer.

Comment: Yes - this line is a bug  "bend = props.bend". Either commend this line or un-comment the property inside __init__.py

Comment: @JakeD Yes, I believe he means to delete the comment hashtags, not the core commented text. In other words, make it used code again.