# Creating Sapling Tree in the Python Console still not working

Tags: python, sapling-addon

I encountered an error adding a tree using sapling in the python console, see here:

[Creating Sapling Tree in the Python Console](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/76693/creating-sapling-tree-in-the-python-console)

and the suggested solution was to use INVOKE_DEFAULT.

However I tried using the INVOKE_DEFAULT and although it adds the object, it does not use the parameters I passed in. It is using the default settings for the tree_add. How do I get it to use my parameters?

I should also mention I tried the other execution contexts and none gave the desired result. (Asking this question in a new thread as requested).

Comment: Same issue, new user here.