# Sapling Tree Generator from Python console

Tags: python, sapling-addon

This question has been asked multiple times, but the solutions still do not work.
I am trying to create a sapling tree from the Python console.

The command copied from the info console + "INVOKE_DEFAULT" give only the standard tree, even if the parameters have been modified.

Comment: It appears that is still in need of edit mentioned here https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/76693/creating-sapling-tree-in-the-python-console

Comment: Edited previous answer, and tested against my 2.83 build and sapling addon provided.